# Drag and drop, wxEVT_DROP_FILES event not received

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

Using wxWidgets wxWidgets-3.0.2 and MSVC 2012 (building with 2008)

I try to add file drag n drop event on wxListView control. When I drag file on control I can see icon change, but when it is released nothing happens, my event handler function is never called.

Code:

```
m_listAllStrings = new wxListView(this, ID_LV_ALLSTRINGS);
m_listAllStrings->DragAcceptFiles(true);
m_listAllStrings->Bind(wxEVT_DROP_FILES, &MainFrame::OnDropFiles, this);
// also tried these
// m_listAllStrings->Connect(wxEVT_DROP_FILES, wxDropFilesEventHandler(MainFrame::OnDropFiles), NULL, this);
// Connect(wxEVT_DROP_FILES, wxDropFilesEventHandler(MainFrame::OnDropFiles)); 

// even handler function
void MainFrame::OnDropFiles(wxDropFilesEvent& event)
{
    // I put breakpoint here, it never enters
    if(event.GetNumberOfFiles() > 0)
    {
         // ...
    }
}
```

I also tried doing this on button and it did not work, though click event handling works:

```
 Connect(wxEVT_COMMAND_BUTTON_CLICKED, wxCommandEventHandler(MainFrame::OnBtClick));
```

Comment: what do you mean by saying "(building with 2008)"? Also, can you reproduce it with the dnd sample?

Comment: platform toolset is set to "Visual Studio 2008 (v90)"; dnd appears to be working but then again I can not drag files from external window like explorer, I guess I will try to use this method if current one will not work out.

Comment: can you try to compile and run the sample and the application with the same run-time/version of MSVC?

Comment: I don't see how platform toolset has anything to do with the issue. However I am now using modified dnd version and it works, it shows weird move icon and I have no idea how to change it. Also drag and drop seems to be not working when app is run with debuger or with admin rights, probably some permission issues here.

Comment: then all you need to do is find what is different between the sample and your code if the sample started working for you.

Comment: Well sample is using different method - `SetDropTarget` with `wxFileDropTarget`. It is working for me as well, but still question is why `DragAcceptFiles` method does not work.

Comment: Can you try DragAcceptFiles() in the sample?

Comment: Where is the sample located? I don't see any sample using `DragAcceptFiles` in 3.0.2 or 3.0.1

Comment: it is a dnd sample that located in the <wx_build>/samples/dnd directory. Can you modify it to use the function in question, re-compile and re-run?